# What happens if Windows service doesn't exit a thread when stopping?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have a .NET Windows service that runs multiple threads. A developer added some new threads to it but forgot to add code to exit the threads before the service stops. When I stop the service, it appears to stop normally, but the exe process continues running for several seconds after the service has stopped. What is happening during this time and what happens to the threads?

Comment: [If you return from the main thread, does the process exit?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/27/10054832.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean. I think my OnStop() override is returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't terminate the threads, but handle the ServiceStop message correctly, the other threads continue to run for ~20 secs, then the OS kills off the service process, killing the threads along the way.

Doesn't seem to do any harm, in general.

Comment: That was one hell of a lot of edits there ;) Thank you. That's kind of what I've gathered through observation. I guess I'm wondering more why there is that 20 sec delay? I always assumed the service manager considered the service "Stopped" when the process exited but that's not the case. Whether it does any harm depends on what the thread is doing when it's killed doesn't it?

Comment: 'hell of a lot of edits' - my ISP is crap and I kept getting errors, so  I tried to edit again later, got errors...   The 20 sec delay is, I guess, giving the service time to clean up it act, should it need to do so.  'Harm', well, yes. The only things I've tried are 100% CPU loops and Sleep(aLot) loops, as a test - nothing untoward happened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311750/c-sharp-service-application-to-start-endless-thread

Answer (score 2):

I assume the delay is there because services tend to do things that are considered "more substantial" than simply servicing button clicks and keystrokes from the user, e.g., closing database connections, disconnecting network connections, stopping drivers, etc.  These things may take a few seconds, so the OS grants some amount of time for a clean shutdown.  However, eventually, the OS will terminate the process, which will kill any threads that are still running.

Threads in .NET can be classified as foreground or background threads.  If the threads you are asking about can be terminated abruptly without any undo "harm" to what your service is doing, mark them as [background threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794917/shutting-down-a-windows-service-that-has-threads/2795028#2795028) so that they do not hold up termination of the process.